# Is it valid to ask このグラフによると、カイロの人口がいつ増えてきましたか?

Tags: grammar

In my understanding, 増えてきました means "started to increase". If my understanding is correct, I think I can ask as follows

> このグラフによると、カイロの人口がいつ増えてきましたか?

and the answer must be 1976. What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> このグラフによると(orよれば)、カイロの人口**は**いつ(ごろ)から増えてきましたか？
>   or
>   このグラフによると(orよれば)、カイロの人口**は**いつ(ごろ)から増え始めましたか？

Comment: Is 1976 a correct answer?

Comment: @Choko: I suppose このグラフによると(orよれば)、カイロの人口はいつ(ごろ)*から*増え始めましたか？might be better.

Comment: @Friendly Ghost: <Is 1976 a correct answer?> It is a matter of opinion, isn't it? I would say the population of Cairo has been increasing ever since 1960, as the data for prior years are not given.

Comment: @Choko Why did you replace が with は?

Comment: @Kaizokugari Hmm.. why? なんでかな・・・？ But you'd say ジョンさん**は**何歳ですか？ not ジョンさん**が**何歳ですか？, right?

Comment: Would いつから人口**が**増え始めましたか sound better in this word order?

Comment: @Choko Yeah I'm not saying it should be the other way around, I am asking why is は more proper in the given context. Is it because it is a question ?

Comment: @Yang Muye: <Would いつから人口が増え始めましたか sound better in this word order?> I don't know if it sound *better* but methinks it sounds natural.

Comment: @eltonjohn. Thanks. I think so too. It seems to me fronting interrogative words like なぜ and いつ sometimes makes the use of が possible.

Comment: 「いつから～～ **は**増え始めましたか」 and 「いつから～～ **が**増え始めましたか」 both sound fine to me, although 「～～ **が**いつから増え始めましたか」doesn't sound natural. 理由はわかりません。(「～～ **が**増え始めたのはいつですか？」 is okay too. 「～～ **は**増え始めたのはいつですか？」 doesn't sound natural, though.)